# Castelnuovo contraction for analytic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex manifold of complex dimension $2$, and let $C$ be a ($-1$)-curve on $X$. Can $C$ be blown down?

Comment: Are you assuming $C$ is smooth rational? Otherwise, in general not, at least in the algebraic category.

Comment: Yes, $C$ is smooth and rational.

Comment: In the algebraic category, this is Catelnuovo. Are you specifically interested only in the analytic category?

Comment: Yes, that's right (and just a reference is perfectly fine).

Comment: Sorry, I know too little about analytic categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the analytic counterpart to Castelnuovo's theorem is sometimes called the Grauert's criterion. See chapter 3 of [Compact Complex Surfaces](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540008323). 
This comes from a more general theorem by Grauert, se page 14 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0208058.pdf). Hartshorne also compares the analytic vs algebraic aspects in chapter 5 of [Algebraic Geometry](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387902449).